# C# implicit conversion issue

Tags: c#

Ok, I have the entire thing working until I get to the part after the break; At this point the If says unreachable code detected and the if(Session["UserType"] = 1) gives an error saying cannot implicitly convert type object to type bool. Any suggestions on how to fix this? The following is the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void  // ERROR: Handles clauses are not supported in C#
    btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text))))
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Username must be entered.";
            txtUserName.Focus();
            return;
        }

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString);
        string sql = "Select * From TCustomers";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader objDR = default(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand objCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();

        objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        bool blnLogin = false;
        string strPassword = null;
        string strUserName = null;
        strPassword = txtPassword.Text;
        strPassword = strPassword.Trim();
        strUserName = txtUserName.Text;
        strUserName = strUserName.Trim();

        while (objDR.Read())
        {
            if (((objDR["strUserName"].ToString().Trim() == strUserName)) & ((objDR["strPassword"].ToString().Trim() == strPassword)))
            {
                blnLogin = true;
                Session["CustomerID"] = objDR["intCustomerID"];
                Session["UserName"] = objDR["strUserName"];
                Session["FirstName"] = objDR["strFirstName"];
                Session["LastName"] = objDR["strLastName"];
                Session["Email"] = objDR["strEmailAddress"];
                Session["UserType"] = objDR["intUserTypeID"];
                break;

                if ((blnLogin))
                {
                    if(Session["UserType"] = 1)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("EditAccount.aspx");
                    }
                    {
                        Session["UserType"] = 2;
                        Response.Redirect("AdminPanel.aspx");
                    }
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code and remove the unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: Now you removed too much :) The previous line contained a `break`.

Comment: Also note, you are likely missing an `else`.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you're doing an assignment instead of a comparison in the code below

```
if(Session["UserType"] = 1)
{
    Response.Redirect("EditAccount.aspx");
}
```

Use `==` instead of `=` to compare.

The result of the assignment is `int`, and `int` cannot be implicitly converted to `bool` in C#. That's the error reported.

If you change `=` to `==` you'll get another error, as you cannot compare the value of `Session["UserType"]` to an `int`. To do that you need to cast it to `int` like this

```
if((int)Session["UserType"] == 1)
{
    Response.Redirect("EditAccount.aspx");
}
```

but keep in mind that this assumes that the value can be cast to `int`. If that is not the case you'll get a run-time error.

There may still be other errors in the code, but you have include more code than my mental compiler can handle.

Comment: He also needs to cast or parse the session variable into an `int` or am I mistaken?

Comment: I don't think that code is even reached. There's a funky `break;` in there.

Comment: Well as emd said before you need a conversion, but maybe you are using an ENUM then you need a different conversion.

Comment: when I do == it tells me that I cannot apply the opperands to obj and int

Comment: @KeithMontgomery that's because you cannot compare those two directly. You need to cast the value of `Session["UserType"]` to `int` before you compare.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: I didn't downvote but I can see why: You didn't provide working code and you even didn't mention that the provided solution ("use == instead of =") doesn't work on its own as there still is a missing conversion or cast.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(Session["UserType"] = 1)
```

...is an assignment, not a comparison; You probably want something closer to:

```
if((int)Session["UserType"] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement should probably be a comparison not an assignment use

```
if(Session["UserType"] == 1)
```

Your code is unreachable because of the break.

Answer (score 0):

The break statement will exit the while loop. Code below it will not execute. Thus, that code is unreachable.